# Why won't the arrows and close button show up for my lightbox images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

I'm using Lightbox in my site so that users can view my images in a larger size, and for some odd reason the controls won't show up. Haven't been able to figure out what the cause would be. Tried comparing my code to the code on the demo site, but couldn't figure out what I had done wrong. Best I can figure is maybe I accidentally did something with my CSS reset?

```js
<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js">
 lightbox.option({
    'wrapAround': true,
    'alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices': true,
    'showImageNumberLabel': true,
  })
</script>
```

```css
/* CSS Reset */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*End CSS Reset */

body {
    max-width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;   
    font-size: 16px;   
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;  
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;   
    color: #555; 
}

p {
 text-align: center; 
}

/* Nav Bar Styles */

nav {
    text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff; 
 font-size: 1.4em;
 padding: 0;
 padding-top: .5%;
 padding-bottom: .6%;
   
}

ul {
 padding-right: 2%; 
}

.navigation {
    display: inline;
    margin: .5%;
  
}

.logo {
 color:#000; 
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 1%;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
    text-align: center;
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: .5%;  
 font-size: 79%;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff; 
 clear: left;
   
}

.imageGrid {
 width: 100%;
 display: block; 
 text-align: center;

}

.images {
 width: 10%; 

}

.categories {
 font-size: 1.4em; 
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sitewide.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/photography.css">
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<header>
  
    <nav>
        <h1 class="logo">B.Fun Photography &amp; Design</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    
</header>

<h2 class="categories">Landscapes</h2>
<div class="imageGrid">
    <a href="http://www.alsogroup.org/default/assets/File/Help2-700x394.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Blue Ridge Sunset"><img src="http://www.alsogroup.org/default/assets/File/Help2-700x394.jpg" alt="Blue Ridge Sunset" class="images"></a>
    <a href="http://www.alsogroup.org/default/assets/File/Help2-700x394.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Duality"><img src="http://www.alsogroup.org/default/assets/File/Help2-700x394.jpg" alt="Duality" class="images"></a>
    <a href="http://www.alsogroup.org/default/assets/File/Help2-700x394.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Elakala Falls"><img src="http://www.alsogroup.org/default/assets/File/Help2-700x394.jpg" alt="Elakala Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/m.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Methuselah"><img src="img/thumbs/m.jpg" alt="Methuselah" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/occ.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Old City Cemetary"><img src="img/thumbs/occ.jpg" alt="Old City Cemetary" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/mk.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Mcafee's Knob"><img src="img/thumbs/mk.jpg" alt="Mcafee's Knob" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/af.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Appalachian Farmland"><img src="img/thumbs/af.jpg" alt="Appalachian Farmland" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/bf.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Blackwater Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/bf.jpg" alt="Blackwater Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/dh.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Dark Hollows Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/dh.jpg" alt="Dark Hollows Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/ef2.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Elakala Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/ef2.jpg" alt="Elakala Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/hr.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Humpback Rocks"><img src="img/thumbs/hr.jpg" alt="Humpback Rocks" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/lp.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Lindy Point"><img src="img/thumbs/lp.jpg" alt="Lindy Point" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/lps.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Lindy Point Sunset"><img src="img/thumbs/lps.jpg" alt="Lindy Point Sunset" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/to.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The Overlook"><img src="img/thumbs/to.jpg" alt="The Overlook" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/golyat.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Golyat"><img src="img/thumbs/golyat.jpg" alt="Golyat s" class="images"></a>
</div>
<h2 class="categories">Weddings</h2>
 <div class="imageGrid">
    <a href="img/weddings/sweeny/beforeFirstLook.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="#"><img src="img/thumbs/br.jpg" alt="Blue Ridge Sunset" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="#"><img src="img/thumbs/duality.jpg" alt="Duality" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Elakala Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/ef.jpg" alt="Elakala Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Methuselah"><img src="img/thumbs/m.jpg" alt="Methuselah" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Old City Cemetary"><img src="img/thumbs/occ.jpg" alt="Old City Cemetary" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Mcafee's Knob"><img src="img/thumbs/mk.jpg" alt="Mcafee's Knob" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Appalachian Farmland"><img src="img/thumbs/af.jpg" alt="Appalachian Farmland" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Blackwater Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/bf.jpg" alt="Blackwater Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Dark Hollows Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/dh.jpg" alt="Dark Hollows Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Elakala Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/ef2.jpg" alt="Elakala Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Humpback Rocks"><img src="img/thumbs/hr.jpg" alt="Humpback Rocks" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Lindy Point"><img src="img/thumbs/lp.jpg" alt="Lindy Point" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="Lindy Point Sunset"><img src="img/thumbs/lps.jpg" alt="Lindy Point Sunset" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2" data-title="The Overlook"><img src="img/thumbs/to.jpg" alt="The Overlook" class="images"></a>
</div>
<h2 class="categories">Other</h2>
 <div class="imageGrid">
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="#"><img src="img/thumbs/br.jpg" alt="Blue Ridge Sunset" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="#"><img src="img/thumbs/duality.jpg" alt="Duality" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Elakala Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/ef.jpg" alt="Elakala Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Methuselah"><img src="img/thumbs/m.jpg" alt="Methuselah" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Old City Cemetary"><img src="img/thumbs/occ.jpg" alt="Old City Cemetary" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Mcafee's Knob"><img src="img/thumbs/mk.jpg" alt="Mcafee's Knob" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Appalachian Farmland"><img src="img/thumbs/af.jpg" alt="Appalachian Farmland" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Blackwater Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/bf.jpg" alt="Blackwater Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Dark Hollows Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/dh.jpg" alt="Dark Hollows Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Elakala Falls"><img src="img/thumbs/ef2.jpg" alt="Elakala Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Humpback Rocks"><img src="img/thumbs/hr.jpg" alt="Humpback Rocks" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Lindy Point"><img src="img/thumbs/lp.jpg" alt="Lindy Point" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Lindy Point Sunset"><img src="img/thumbs/lps.jpg" alt="Lindy Point Sunset" class="images"></a>
    <a href="img/weddings/#.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The Overlook"><img src="img/thumbs/to.jpg" alt="The Overlook" class="images"></a>
</div>



<footer>
    <p>&#169; 2016 Brian Funderburke. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</footer>
<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js">
 lightbox.option({
    'wrapAround': true,
    'alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices': true,
    'showImageNumberLabel': true,
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From the plugin: "Add a data-lightbox attribute to any image link to enable Lightbox. For the value of the attribute, use a unique name for each image." You use image-1 for all the images, it should be image-1, image-2,...

Comment: @Alexander but it said to do that if you wanted images to be in an album which is what I wanted? Or at least that's what I thought it said.